# Calling selector doesn't call delegate method in separate thread

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(colourChange) toTarget:del withObject:nil];
```

This should call the colourChange method in the class' delegate(del) but it doesn't?

I checked del != nil, using the debugger I checked its pointing to the delegate.

resolved with

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), 
                           ^{
                               [del colourChange]; 
                          });
```

check the link in the marked answer below for further details.

Comment: check that del is not nil, also post some code here

Comment: what code would you like. the colourChange method is simply - (void)colourChange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know(from core data) a method can just be called from the thread it is created in. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295017/what-are-the-different-ways-for-calling-my-method-on-separate-thread) question(with answer) may be useful for you

Comment: Cheers, I've got it working using GCD. That link is fantastic.

Comment: i'm pleased if it worked. i myself prefer GCD&blocks too most of times

Comment: @ilis: Your first sentence doesn't make sense. Objective-C methods aren't created and they are never bound to a specific thread.

Comment: @Codo I couldn't see where i had read that from but i remember something like that. That is why i started the answer with "As far as i know..". If i can find i will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your method has the wrong signature. It must take a single argument (see [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

> The selector for the message to send to the target. This selector must
>   take only one argument and must not have a return value.